# Token renewal operation failed due to timeout: null in MSAL.js

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

When I try to obtain an access token using MSAL.js I'm receiving:

> Token renewal operation failed due to timeout: null

How do I debug this?

And why don't I see the network traffic in Chrome for this hidden `iframe`?  I see them in Edge.

Comment: [Related Github Issue](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/209)